# consulta pra sql

Tags: sql

Seleccione los nombres de las ciudades que empiecen con “Kal”

cual seria el comando para esta consulta

Comment: Tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y es seguro termine cerrada, lee [ask]

Answer (score 1):

En este caso para seleccionar los nombres de las ciudades que empiecen con "Kal", puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
select nombre from ciudades where nombre like 'Kal%'
```

donde "ciudades" es la tabla y "nombre" es el campo que contiene el nombre de las ciudades. Si quisieras obtener las ciudades que terminan con "Kal", solo tendrias que cambiar el caracter "%" al inicio:

```
select nombre from ciudades where nombre like '%Kal'
```

o si quieres puedes obtener los nombres de las ciudades que contienen la palabra "Kal":

```
select nombre from ciudades where nombre like '%Kal%'
```

Comment: gracias por la ayuda  :)